# Unity Unet Multiplayer issue with iOS native build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I created my how matchmaking class with unity. It all works fine on pc and am easily able to create a match without no problems. The problems came when I try to create a match for iOS.

When I try to create a new match I got this error on Xcode:

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.

Parameter name: baseUri

at System.Uri.Merge (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at UnityEngine.Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.ListMatches (UnityEngine.Networking.Match.ListMatchRequest req, UnityEngine.Networking.Match.ResponseDelegate`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 


(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

Here is the code that use to crete the match:

```
void Start()
    {
        networkMatch = gameObject.AddComponent<NetworkMatch>();
    }

private void OnMatchCreate(CreateMatchResponse matchResponse)
    {
        if (matchResponse.success)
        {           
            NetworkServer.ClearLocalObjects ();
            NetworkServer.ClearSpawners ();
            NetworkServer.SetAllClientsNotReady ();
            Debug.Log("Create match succeeded");
            matchCreated = true;
            Utility.SetAccessTokenForNetwork(matchResponse.networkId, new NetworkAccessToken(matchResponse.accessTokenString));
            NetworkServer.Listen(new MatchInfo(matchResponse), 9000);
            UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkManager.singleton.StartServer(new MatchInfo(matchResponse));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError ("Create match failed");
        }
    }
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation a bit I found a solution to this problem:

- Be sure the initialization of the network take place into the Start method
- Set the mach URI to use for the matching.

Final code:

```
void Start()
    {

        networkMatch = gameObject.AddComponent<NetworkMatch>();
        networkMatch.baseUri = new System.Uri("https://mm.unet.unity3d.com/");          
    }
```

The URL is the default URL provided by Unity

Comment: As of Unity 2017.3.0f3 on iOS this is still an issue, and this solution worked for me.